# React useState not updating, in socket.io events

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, webrtc

I am trying to update my state in a socket.io event,
but only the most recent changes are reflected , and the previous changes are gone

```js
  const [connStatus, setStatus] = useState({});
  const newConn = (user_id) => {
    console.log("previous ", connStatus);
    console.log("new status ", { ...connStatus, [user_id]: true });
    setStatus({ ...connStatus, [user_id]: true });
  };
```

i am using this fucntion `newConn`to update values,

```js
    props.socket.on("ANSWER", (incoming) => {
     
      const desc = new RTCSessionDescription(incoming.sdp);

      peers.current[incoming.caller]
        .setRemoteDescription(desc)
        .then((data) => {
          // set conn as true
          console.log(connStatus, { ...connStatus, [incoming.caller]: true });
          newConn(incoming.caller);
        })
        .catch((e) => console.log(e));
    });
```

The previous state is always logged as empty `{}` i.e its initial value, and new state is updating but discards all the previous values.

For

```js
newConn("key1"); newConn("key2");
```

the logs look like this

```
previous {}
new status {"key1" : true}

previous {}
new status {"key2" : true}
```

using a function signature like

```js
  const newConn = (user_id) => {
    setStatus((prevState) => {
      console.log("previous ", prevState);
      console.log("new status ", { ...prevState, [user_id]: true });
      return { ...connStatus, [user_id]: true };
    });
  };
```

For

```js
newConn("key1"); newConn("key2"); newConn("key3");
```

the logs looks like this

```js
previous {}
new status {"key1" : true}

previous {"key1" : true}
new status {"key1" : true,"key2" : true}

previous {"key2" : true}
new status {"key2" : true,"key3" : true}
```

**UPDATE**

I have found the solution , but not sure why it works and my previous attempts don't

```js
  const newConn = (user_id) => {
    setStatus((prevState) => {
      console.log("previous ", prevState);
      console.log("new status ", { ...prevState, [user_id]: true });
      const newState = { ...prevState, [user_id]: true };

      return newState;
    });
  };
```

Using `newConn` gives me the required output.

Comment: Can you post the structure of connStatus?

Comment: @Mark i've updated the post, hope it helps, connStatus is just an object with
```{ [string] : bool
}``` structure

Answer (score 1):

Use the function signature of the `setStatus`:

```
const [connStatus, setStatus] = useState({});
const newConn = (user_id) => {
    console.log("previous ", connStatus);
    console.log("new status ", { ...connStatus, [user_id]: true });
    setStatus(s => ({ ...s.connStatus, [user_id]: true }));
           // ^ HERE
  };
```

Comment: i think you mean ,  ```setStatus(s => ({ ...connStatus, [user_id]: true }));``` cause ```s.connStatus``` is null, but even the function signature does'nt work.

Comment: @sasta_achar, the whole point of function is to use `previousState`, noted as `s` here and compute the next state. so `...s.connState` is actually correct. Also `{ ...null, 1: 1 }` results in `{1:1}`. So what I have is correct. Good luck.

Comment: But if you want to just replace your state as the newState, without using any of the previous state you can just use ```return newState``` , why use the extra ```{...s.key, newState}```, also i think that using prevState (here s) when not required may cause troubles in future , like if my state was like ```state : { connStatus : "some value" }``` then your answer would have caused unwanted results , but since its null in my case, it worked fine